# Adding video link field to RSS

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

I am trying to add a video link to my RSS field.

for example.

Here is a link to a post I want to extract a video link from: http://topdailyfights.com/index.php/09/20/employee-goes-crazy-in-office/

The link I want is in "video-wrap" div class.

```
<div class="video-wrap"><div class='jwplayer' id='jwplayer-0'></div><script type='text/javascript'>if(typeof(jQuery)=="function"){(function($){$.fn.fitVids=function(){}})(jQuery)};jwplayer('jwplayer-0').setup({"aspectratio":null,"width":420,"height":315,"primary":"flash","file":"http://topdailyfights.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/office-worker-goes-crazy.mp4"});
</script></div>
```

This is the link I want: topdailyfights.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/office-worker-goes-crazy.mp4

I want links to show up under every feed: http://topdailyfights.com/index.php/feed/

How do I do this?

feed.php code (if that helps): [pastebin.com/sfHuPETv](http://pastebin.com/sfHuPETv)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a great class the other day when i was doing something similar, its called simplehtmldom and you can get it [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Simple demo:

```
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://slashdot.org/');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('div.article') as $article) {
    $item['title']     = $article->find('div.title', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['intro']    = $article->find('div.intro', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['details'] = $article->find('div.details', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```

Comment: That's interesting. I will check it out.

Comment: Let me know if i can be of any help further